# when do you prefer to use non clustered index over clustered index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've some knowledge of using clustered index and non clustered index, but I'm not sure when and on what conditions it would be helpful to use non clustered index over clustered index. can someone explain or provide some links so that it would be helpful to all of us.

Comment: when you already have a clustered index?

Comment: clustered index will sort all your data accordingly when u do select statement without order by, and it normally bundle together with primary key(it will be only max 1 clustered index per table), non clustered index can be create if clustered index already created to speed up your selection. So the only helpful part is clustered index already mapped with primary key so you have to use non-clustered which is what @wRAR said.

Comment: no i just have a table and it doesn't have any clustered index o non clustered index defined over it. so what are the conditions should i consider before using a clustered or non-clustered index

Answer (score 1):

pick your clustered index! Every "regular" data table ought to have a clustered index, since having a clustered index does indeed speed up a lot of operations - yes, **speed up**, even inserts and deletes! But only if you pick a **good** clustered index.

It's the **most replicated** data structure in your SQL Server database. The clustering key will be part of each and every non-clustered index on your table, too.

You should use extreme care when picking a clustering key - it should be:

- **narrow** (4 bytes ideal)
- **unique** (it's the "row pointer" after all. If you don't make it unique SQL Server will do it for you in the background, costing you a couple of bytes for each entry times the number of rows and the number of nonclustered indices you have - this can be very costly!)
- **static** (never change - if possible)
- ideally **ever-increasing** so you won't end up with horrible index fragmentation (a GUID is the total opposite of a good clustering key - for that particular reason)
- it should be non-nullable and ideally also fixed width - a `varchar(250)` makes a very poor clustering key

Anything else should really be second and third level of importance behind these points ....

See some of Kimberly Tripp's (*The Queen of Indexing*) blog posts on the topic - anything she has written in her blog is absolutely invaluable - read it, digest it - live by it!

- [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- [The Clustered Index Debate Continues...](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)
- [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx)
- [Disk space is cheap - that's **not** the point!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Disk-space-is-cheap.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A non-clustered index is useful for columns that have some repeated values.
A clustered index is automatically created when we create the primary key for the table. We need to take care of the creation of the non-clustered index.
clustered index is one per table, When creating the clustered index, SQL server 2005 reads the column and forms a Binary tree on it. This binary tree information is then stored separately in the disc. With the use of the binary tree, now the search for the specific value based on the column decreases the number of comparisons to a large amount.